# Pass access_token to request module, nodejs

Tags: node.js

I would like to pass an access token to Google when retrieving a file in Drive api. Trying different syntaxes gave nothing and auth() seems to only handle user/password couple.
Here is what I had in mind:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream('./42');
request(req.body.url,{'headers':{'auth':req.apiAuth}}, function(err,response){
});
```

Or :

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream('./43-1');
request({url:req.body.url,auth:req.apiAuth}, function(err,response){
});
```

Request readme didn't help me unfortunately !

Comment: If that's an `oauth` token, use an `oauth` client. It's not the same as basic HTTP auth.

Comment: It's a service account token, which is a oauth I believe. Do you mean I will have to use google drive library ?

Comment: Could be. Using `oauth2` is unfortunately not simple. If there's a specialized client you can use, go for it. If not, you'll need to read up a bit on how `oauth2` works.